# ¿Porqué éstos errores cuando paso el problema de la mochila a interfaz gráfica?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Quiero pasar el codigo de el problema de la mochila a Interfaz grafica, pero me surgen unos errores y dudas al momento de hacerlo, como haria para que me salgan los datos en la interfaz grafica(hay aparte una clase llamada beneficio donde tengo mis variables de beneficio, peso y bxp(beneficioxpeso))[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

```
public void metodoMochila(){

    int p = Integer.parseInt(this.txtpesogenerado01.getText());
                int q = (int)Integer.parseInt(this.txtpesogenerado02.getText());
                float solucion[] = new float [p];// tipo unidimensional (vector);
        Beneficio objetos[] = new Beneficio[p];
        llenar(objetos); // ingresamos los valores
        mostrar(objetos); //muestra los elementos ingresados
        directa(objetos); // ordena de acuerdo a nuestra funcion seleccion
        mostrar(objetos); // muestra los elementos ordenados
        objetivo(solucion , objetos); // resuelve el problema
        mostrar(solucion,objetos); // muestra la solucion

    }



    //funcion para llenar los vectores
    public static void llenar(Beneficio vector []  ){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < vector.length ;i++) {

         //int n =(int) Float.parseFloat(btxtPrimos.getText());
        int p1 = (int )Float.parseFloat(txtpesogenerado01.getText().toString()+(i+1));
        int p2 = (int) Float.parseFloat(txtpesogenerado02.getText().toString+(i+1));
        int p3 = (int) Float.parseInt(txtpesogenerado03.getText().toString()+(i+1));
        int p4 = (int) Float.parseInt(txtpesogenerado04.getText().toString()+(i+1));    
        int b1 = (int) Float.parseInt(txtbeneficiogenerado01.getText().toString()+(i+1));
        int b2 = (int) Float.parseInt(txtbeneficiogenerado02.getText().toString()+(i+1));
        int b3 = (int) Float.parseInt(txtbeneficiogenerado03.getText().toString()+(i+1));
        int b4 = (int) Float.parseInt(txtbeneficiogenerado04.getText().toString()+(i+1));
        vector[i]= new Beneficio (p1,b1); // calcula el bxp
        vector[i]= new Beneficio (p2,b2); // calcula el bxp
        vector[i]= new Beneficio (p3,b3); // calcula el bxp
        vector[i]= new Beneficio (p4,b4); // calcula el bxp

    }
        }


    //funcion para ordenar segun el beneficio por unidad 
    public static void directa(Beneficio [] vector )
    {

    int i,k,j;
    double menor;
    Beneficio aux = new Beneficio();
    aux = vector[0];

    for(i=0 ; i<vector.length;i++ )
    {
        menor=vector[i].getBxp();
        k=i;

        for(j=i+1 ; j<vector.length;j++ )
        { 
            if(vector[j].getBxp()< menor) // ordena el valor por bxp
            {
            menor=vector[j].getBxp();
            aux= vector[j];
            k=j;

            }

        }
        aux= vector[k];
        vector[k]=vector[i];
        vector[i]=aux;

    }

    }

    public static void mostrar(Beneficio [] aux )
    { String beneficio="beneficio:  ",peso = "peso" , valor="valor por unidad:  " ;
        for(int i=0 ; i<aux.length;i++)
        {
            beneficio+= aux[i].getBeneficio() + "  ,  ";
            peso += aux[i].getPeso() + " , ";
            valor += (aux[i].getBeneficio() / aux[i].getPeso())  + " , ";

        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, peso + "\n" + beneficio + "\n" + valor ); 
    }

    public static void mostrar(float aux [] , Beneficio b [])
    { String solucion=" solucion:  " ;
      float suma = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<aux.length;i++)
        {
            solucion += aux[i]+ "-------";
            suma+= aux[i]*b[i].getBeneficio();
        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, solucion  + "\n total beneficio: "  + suma ); 
    }


//funcion para seleccionar los objetos:
        //MAX F.O:

public static void objetivo(float solucion[], Beneficio objetos[]) // envia un vector solucion ()
{
 //int m = (int) Integer.parseFloat(this.txtpesoTotal.getText());
  //int m =(int) Float.parseFloat(btxtPesoTotal.getText());
  int m = Integer.parseFloat(btxtPesoTotal.getText().toString());
float pesoactual= 0;
 int i = solucion.length-1;// empieza a recorrerlo desde el final por haber ordenado de mayor a menor

   while(pesoactual < m  || i>= 0)
   { 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " peso actual: "+ pesoactual +  "   peso objeto " + i + "  :" + objetos[i].getPeso() + "\n  ");

      if( (pesoactual + objetos[i].getPeso()) < m ) //<--- el objeto que se tomará
      {
          solucion[i]= 1;
          pesoactual+= objetos[i].getPeso();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " peso actual: "+ pesoactual +  "   porcentaje tomado del objeto  " + i + "  :" +  solucion[i]*100 + "\n  ");
      }
      else

      {
         solucion[i]=(m-pesoactual)/objetos[i].getPeso();
         pesoactual += ((m-pesoactual)/objetos[i].getPeso())* objetos[i].getPeso();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " peso actual: "+ pesoactual +  "   porcentaje tomado del objeto  " + i + "  :" +  solucion[i]*100 + "\n  "); 
      //fraccionamos_/
          }

    i--;   
   }
}
```

Comment: Estoy bastante seguro que los errores se deben a errores de sintaxis. Me di cuenta de varias cosas, la primera es:  
**No hace falta escribir toString(  ) a un campo que ya es String**.  
La segunda, es que **no puedes utilizar Float.parseInt(...); si quieres convertir a entero, utiliza Integer.parseInt(...), y si es algún Float, entonces utiliza su respectivo método, que sería Float.parseFloat(...)**. Lo tercero es una duda sobre si **el último caracter escrito es un 1 o una L minúscula**. Y lo último es que **te falta un paréntesis en la segunda línea de error**

Comment: Hola @C.Rodriguez , he cambiado los datos , le borre el **.toString()**, puse su respectivo metodo y me sigue arrojando error... El último carácter escrito es un **1**.

Comment: Perfecto  @Andreso, solo una duda más, al colocar el puntero del ratón sobre el símbolo de alerta, o el bombillo, ¿qué error muestra?